# Move content out and in and bettween different bootstrap4 tab bars

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have multiple divs with bootstrap tabs (using collapse) side by side as you can see here:
https://codepen.io/MichaelBootstrap/pen/wvMZOob

```
<div id="mgvo-content">
  <div id="mgvo-main" class="mgvo-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mgvo-submenu mgvo-main-submenu">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mgvo-main-m1">Hauptmenu</a></li>
      <li class="mgvo-submenu-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mgvo-main-m2">Menu 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mgvo-tab-content tab-content">
      <div id="mgvo-main-m1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      </div>
      <div id="mgvo-main-m2" class="tab-pane fade mgvo-tab-content-item"> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mgvo-side1" class="mgvo-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mgvo-submenu">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mgvo-side1-m1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="mgvo-submenu-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mgvo-side1-m2">Menu 1a</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="mgvo-tab-content tab-content">
      <div id="mgvo-side1-m1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
       </div>
      <div id="mgvo-side1-m2" class="tab-pane fade mgvo-tab-content-item">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="mgvo-side2" class="mgvo-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs mgvo-submenu">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mgvo-side2-m1">Home</a></li>
      <li class="mgvo-submenu-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mgvo-side2-m2">Menu 1b</a></li>
     </ul>

    <div class="mgvo-tab-content tab-content">
      <div id="mgvo-side2-m1" class="tab-pane fade  in active">
      </div>
      <div id="mgvo-side2-2" class="tab-pane fade mgvo-tab-content-item">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

For large sceens thats fine, but of cause, on smaller screens if have to collapse the 3 tab bars to one (an one mobile to a burger menu). Collapse the tabs to one isn't a big thing, ever tab bar contain all entry s and based on sm, md, xl they are displayed.

But i'm worry about how to move the content (which can be a form with current unsaved changes) from one tab bar to the first on.
The first idea: set up a Java Script with triggers each window size change and find out if a breakpoint is hit, if, then move the content with jquery from one tab bar to the other. But watch each change of window ist little bit ineffient.

Has any one a better idea? May using CSS an Bootstrap4 only? (Some mixin, CSS before/after)

Concrete questions: How can collapse side1 und side2 (see codepen) into the first tab bar on smaler screens. May the solutions does not "move" anythink but change some views.
I'd didn't need a complete coding, an idea will be fine.
(one option will may be, the the upper tab bars are not 3 diffent bars but only one which if formated to look like 3 (with some align ..) but thats just a guess ..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is exactly good practice but you can always use the .d-none class in bootstrap to hide elements based on breakpoints and d-block to show them.

For example

```
.d-xl-none
```

Hides an element only in the extra large breakpoint.

The downside would be having to repeat some elements.

Comment: Since the element is in most cases a form, which may have current changes by the user, there is no way to repeat content (for static content this will be a solution).